# Angular Unit Testing Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, controllers

My controller doesnt do a lot other than call methods in a service, the service wraps up and returns its functions, I have already written unit tests for the service mocking the http request.

Is it even worth unit testing the controller in this instance and if so what would I be testing as I have already tested the service functionality.

Below is my controller:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var calculatorControllers = angular.module('calculatorControllers', []);

 calculatorControllers.controller('BodyController', ['$scope',
function($scope) {
   $scope.toggleNavBarActive = function($event) {            
       $($event.currentTarget).parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $($event.currentTarget).addClass('active');
   };
}]);

calculatorControllers.controller('CalculatorCtrl', ['$scope',    'CalculatorService',
function($scope, CalculatorService) {
$scope.orderProp = 'asc';
$scope.result = ' awaiting calculation';
$scope.sum = {};   

$scope.add = function(val1, val2) {         
    var promise = CalculatorService.add(val1, val2);  
    promise.then(function(response) {
        $scope.result = response;
    });     
};   
}]);

calculatorControllers.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {

}]);
```

Comment: Please post the code of your controller. Otherwise, the question is too broad.

Comment: In my app, most of my services make requests to APIs and do work on the response before handing the promise back to the controller.  My controllers usually do minimal work on the response before the template consumes the data.  There are some cases that I modify the data before then, and in that case it might warrant unit testing the response.  It really depends on how easy and modular your controller APIs are.  BTW do you do jujitsu?  Just asking because of your username.

Comment: Hey yes I do jiu jitsu, do you? I am a purple belt at the moment. I wish I was a purple belt in Angular but I feel like a white no stripe...

Comment: As requested by @Pavlo can you include the controller in question...

Comment: At the moment I just want to test the calculator controller, I will worry about the body controller once I know roughly what I am doing.

Comment: Based on what I see in your controller, it doesn't really warrant setting up for unit testing.  Of course test driven development is always recommended.  The usual use case for something like unit testing the controller is when a response may affect a larger data structure that wasn't explicitly represented in the request. Good to meet another jujitiero.  Almost a purple myself.  Soon I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it even worth unit testing the controller in this instance

Yes, you should aim for 100% coverage, not matter controller or service. I would test two things here (Jasmine):

```
it('inits $scope', function() {
  var $scope = {};
  $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });

  expect($scope.orderProp).toEqual('asc');
  expect($scope.result).toEqual(' awaiting calculation');
  expect($scope.sum).toEqual({});
});

it('calls CalculatorService and sets the result', function() {
  var $scope = {};
  $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });

  $scope.sum(1, 2);
  expect(CalculatorServiceMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);

  resolveCalculatorServiceMockAddSpyWith(3);
  expect($scope.result).toEqual(3);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only case when the controller methods don't require testing is

```
$scope.calculator = CalculatorService;
```

So all view calls like `{{ calculator.sum(...) }}` are done by the service.

In every other case controller methods should be tested. Since `CalculatorService` unit was already tested, it has to be mocked in order for controller logic to be tested in isolation.